# dependencies not showing in package.json in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am new to node.js. I know when I install a new module in node.js using npm install  it gets installed but in package.json i cant find the package name in dependencies. I know i can type it out but it should appear when i install it using command prompt it should appear. Here's my package.json file. `

```
{
  "name": "mapfeedback-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Map feedback Javascript Test library 1.0",
  "main": "client.js",
  "bin": {
    "mapfeedback-test": "server.js"
  },
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ssh://jasharma@gerrit.it.here.com:29418/CommunityPlatform/testing/mapfeedback-test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [] }
```

Please advice and let me know if I am wrong at something.

I use `npm install` command to install all the packages but its not showing in the dependencies.

`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quickest way to fix this would be to run:

```
npm install <dependencies listed here> --save
```

And that should add them to the package.json

#### Update:

Couple of extra commands for future viewers of the OP:

To add the package to your `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies`

`npm install <dependencies listed here> --save-dev`

---

There are also some handy shortcuts for both commands:

**dependencies:**

- `npm i <dependencies listed here> -S`

**dev-dependencies:**

- `npm i <dependencies listed here> -D`

---

[The npm documentation is here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/)

[And if you are a fan of shortcuts and npm configuration here is a useful link to find even more.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties)

Comment: somehow, I needed to close vscode and reopen it - and type the suggestion here to see the dependencies {} in the package.json

Answer (score 5):

For npm packages to appear in package.json automatically you need to use this command:

```
 npm install packagename --save
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following command

```
npm install <pkg-name> --save
```

> --save
>    instructs npm to include package  inside dependencies of package.json

Answer (score 1):

You need to install using --save or --save-dev switches.

Official documentation on this page: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Answer (score 0):

i had that problem on linux and i figured out that i just use `npm i <pkgs list here>` to install my dependencies. then i used this command to install them:

```
npm i -S <pkgs list here>
```

the `-S` will save them as dependencies and puts the list of installed pkgs under `dependencies: { ... }` object in `package.json` file.

please note that without `-S` flag , npm will install them but not list them in `package.json` file

Answer (score 0):

If You are on linux or a mac and you have not configured your permissions very well You may need to prefix sudo 
`sudo npm install <dependencies listed here> --save`

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code:
npm install --save packagename