# problem in installing the node modules and building next

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, installation, node-modules

[image: I have problem in installing the node modules and building next]

just installation doesn't work , if I installed any frameworks ,it shows in package.json file ( i don't have node modules folder here). so if I tried to install node modules, it says it is installed but it doesn't show up in folder section. if I give npm install next.. it installs next , it shows next is successfully installed but It doesn't show up.. i thought I have error on cache files..so I deleted caches but still it doesn't node modules doesn't show up.it has two folder - local and roaming
random youtuber said so I tried to delete them and run it.. and install node js again.. then i tried it didn't work out at all[image: node_modules missing not installed after the command]

( he told : delete npm and npm cache folder and delete node js and reinstall them. )
I tried this below shown one , but didnt work.
[dependencies not showing in package.json in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180439/dependencies-not-showing-in-package-json-in-node-js)

my issues is not about installing dependencies and dev-dependencies, my issue is about the  node modules folder is not showing after installing node modules.

my package.json file :

```js
 {
  "name": "ebay-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "main": "next.config.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the tailwindcss library
by one of these commands:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

Comment: I tried , it is installed already

Answer (score 0):

I solved this !! because it has permission problems.

I tried the cmd with run as administrator.

it worked. so installed all my dependencies correctly after that.